# Send a list<something> to the Controller from the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form that will be filled, and there is a part where you can check in the checkboxes to add keywords to the object. I have a Model Keyword and a Model of Product, product has a List. I need to fill it up before I add it to the database. This is my code in the View.

```
        <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Price" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Details" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Details" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Details" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ProductionTimeInDays" class="control-label">Production Time In Days</label>
            <input asp-for="ProductionTimeInDays" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ProductionTimeInDays" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Keywords</label>

            @foreach(Keyword word in keywordsList)
                {
                    <input type="checkbox" name="keywords" value="@word.Word" /> @word.Word<br/>
                }

            <span class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

How can I send the information to the controller?

Comment: You are overriding the name property with each iteration. The name property needs to be unique so the backend can retrieve data from the request.

Comment: Assumed `keywordsList` is a `List<Keyword>`, all of the checkbox created by loop has `name="keywords"` attribute, which only one value is passed afterwards. If you want multiple values from them, use different indexes.

Comment: I have seen in some tutorials, they use the same name, so if I have multiple choices, they all belong to one, for example: if I had name vehicles, and had many checkboxes with name vehicles, then I could have checked VW, Chevrolet, and so on. And they could be returned as a list.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have in controller the:

```
public List<Keyword> kewordsList{ get; set; } = new List<Keyword>();
```

But before you must have in your model class Keyword:

```
public bool Checked { get; set; } // the name is written by me you can choose any name you want
```

A checkbox need to be a Boolean type and after that you can use it in your form:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.keywordsList.Count(); i++)
{
<input asp-for="keywordsList[i].Checked" />
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. Instead of sending an object, I changed to send the ID, and in the controller I would be receiving an array of Ids.